# Select and sort a column in a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table, tablesort

I want to select a particular column of a table and sort it accordingly using Javascript (No frameworks or plugins). Could anyone help me regarding this?

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Col1</td>
                <td>Col2</td>
                <td>Col3</td>
                <td>Col4</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Data11</td>
                <td>Data23</td>
                <td>Data53</td>
                <td>Data45</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data81</td>
                <td>Data42</td>
                <td>Data33</td>
                <td>Data4854</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Data84681</td>
                <td>Data452</td>
                <td>Data354</td>
                <td>Data448</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Data1846</td>
                <td>Data25635</td>
                <td>Data3232</td>
                <td>Data44378</td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function sortTableByColumn(tableId,columnNumber) { // (string,integer)
  var tableElement=document.getElementById(tableId);
  [].slice.call(tableElement.tBodies[0].rows).sort(function(a, b) {
    return (
      a.cells[columnNumber-1].textContent<b.cells[columnNumber-1].textContent?-1:
      a.cells[columnNumber-1].textContent>b.cells[columnNumber-1].textContent?1:
      0);
  }).forEach(function(val, index) {
    tableElement.tBodies[0].appendChild(val);
  });
}
```

In your page, add id to the table tag:

```
<table id="myTable">
```

From javascript, use:

```
sortTableByColumn("myTable",3);
```

`tBodies[0]` is used because there can be many.  In your example there is only one.

If we have `var arr=[123,456,789]`, `[].slice.call(arr)` returns a copy of arr.

We're feeding it the html-rows-collection, found in `tBodies[0]` of `tableElement`.

Then, we sort that array with an inline function that compares two array elements, here: rows (`<tr>`).

Using `cells[columnNumber]` we access the `<td>`s, and `textContent` to access the text content.  I've used `columnNumber-1` so you can enter 3 for third column instead of 2, because the index of first element of an array (column 1) is 0...

The `forEach` goes through the elements of the array, which is by now in order, and `appendChild` row to the tBody.  Because it already exist, it just moves it to the end: moving the lowest value to the end, then moving the second lowest to the (new) end, until it ends with the highest value, at the end.

I hope this is what you want.  If so, enjoy!

Comment: You said "select" - if you mean by clicking on a column header, let me know.  I've done that as well, and will try to remember to share that here as well.

Comment: The only downside is that it doesn't "one shot" the appending, I'm assuming in a large table there might be some visual ordering, I guess you could copy the rows in an array and change the table.rows attribute

Comment: Did my answer help you?
If so, please select and up-vote it.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try using datatables you can get it from http://datatables.net its reallt easy to use. depends on jQuery

```
$("table").dataTable();
```

boom! and its done.

Comment: Anyway to do this only using Javascript(no frameworks or plugins)?